# Add mithril's MSX to Laravel Elixir

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mithril.js

I'm using Mithril as my front end framework and Laravel for my back-end. I would love to use this:
https://github.com/insin/msx

But not quite sure how to add it as a plugin to browserify. Is it possible to do it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found this link:
https://github.com/sectore/mithrilify

Installed and works like a charm!